# Representation $\cos(\pi z )$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I already know that
$$
\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}:= \frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n\neq 0} ( \frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n})\ .
$$

However, I am wondering if it also true that

$$
\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}:= \sum_{n} ( \frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n+i})\ ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your second sum in the form
$$
\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{i} + \sum\limits_{n \ne 0} {\left( {\frac{1}{{z - n}} + \frac{1}{{n + i}}} \right)} .
$$
If your guess was true, subtracting the first formula from the second would give
$$
0 = 1 + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2  + 1}}}  > 0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Just a question, in order to do your computations, don't you need absolutelly convergence? I mean, you are changing several times the summation order.

Comment: You can make the procedure more rigorous by considering limits. After subtraction you get $$
0=\frac{1}{i} + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n =  - N,n \ne 0}^N {\left( {\frac{1}{{n + i}} - \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{i} + \frac{2}{i}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{n^2  + 1}}} .
$$